# Get Text Within Div and Find Matching HTML and Add Class

Tags: jquery, css

In my page I have an "A" tag with a specific class:

```
<a class="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode" href="/kmcentre/Pages/Budget.aspx">Budget</a>
```

I need jQuery to find that text (Budget in this case) then find the matching text within a UL:

```
<ul class="BrionStepNav">
<li><a href="Budget.aspx">Budget</a></li>
<li><a href="Category-Management.aspx">Category Management</a></li>
<li><a href="Strategic-Sourcing.aspx">Strategic Sourcing</a></li>
</ul>
```

When it finds matching text I want to add the class "current" using addClass:

```
<li><a href="Budget.aspx" class="current">Budget</a></li>
```

This is what my brain has come up with this far, but no luck:

```
var breadcrumb = $( "a.s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode" ).html();
var stepnav = $( "ul.BrionStepNav li a").html();
$( stepnav ).filter( breadcrumb ).addClass( "current" );
```

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `.text()` , `:contains()` selector

```
var breadcrumb = $("a.s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode" ).text();
var stepnav = $("ul.BrionStepNav li a:contains(" + breadcrumb + ")");
stepnav.addClass("current");
```